# How to read AWS S3 stored word document (.doc and .docx) file content using AWS Lambda Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

My scenario, I am trying to implement read AWS Stored S3 word document (.doc and .docx) file content from Aws Lambda by using python. Below code I am using, My problem is I can able to get the file name but I can’t able to read content.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    file_contents = s3.Object(‘Bucketname’, 'sample.docx').get()['Body'].read().decode("unicode-escape")

    return {
         'File Name' : obj.key,
         ‘Content’ : file_contents
            }
```

> Response: {   "errorMessage": "'unicodeescape' codec can't decode
>   bytes in position 25818-25819: truncated \xXX escape",   "errorType":
>   "UnicodeDecodeError",   "stackTrace": [
>       [
>         "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
>         76,
>         "lambda_handler",
>         "file_contents = s3.Object('Bucketname', 'sample.docx').get()['Body'].read().decode(\"unicode-escape\")"
>       ]   ] }

Comment: You could try decoding the file using a library like textract: https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thank you @NitinLabhishetty. I tried Textract but same issues happening. In local everything working well but inside lambda same issues happening.

Comment: If it works on local and isn't working on lambda, perhaps the lambda does not have access to the s3 object?

Comment: Hi @NitinLabhishetty...when I am trying Textract I am not getting file name at the line "text = textract.process(obj.key)" //Here file name not assigning. I checked by using logs and return statement there I can get but file textract processing line not assigning. Note: Its happening only in Aws Lambda not local.

Comment: Hi, solved? you can read now doc, docx files within lambda from s3?

Answer (score 0):

.docx and .doc files are binary files, so a simple decode won't work, perhaps [docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt)
may help here.

Comment: I tried docx2txt and doc2text both but same issues happening. Thanks lot for your answer @Wolfgang

Comment: how did you use them? as I said, you can't use decode out of the box. what are the error messages?

Comment: I will post what I tried. If I use docx2txt then I need to use doc2text for .doc file...so I need to maintain two separate code....Better Textract is best idea also it's extracting table data..