# Django read from filefield returns hex, how to read doc file from AWS s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

Im builing a django website that matches documents, and I upload documents to Minio bucket, so the defaut storage is storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage from django-storages and not the default Django storage class. This question is similar to
[Why is Django FieldFIle readline() returning the hex version of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59366422/why-is-django-fieldfile-readline-returning-the-hex-version-of-a-text-file)

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'doc_file']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        f = form.instance.doc_file.open('r')
        text = ''.join(i.decode("utf-8", 'ignore') for i in f.readlines())
        form.instance.content = ''.join(
            [i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

So I read the doc, and I pass it into my content field which is a textfield. So when I read a doc its all in hexadecimal so I have to decode it but even after that there are weird characters left . If I upload a .txt file it reads it properly but if I upload a doc file it gives me alot of weird characters even after I do ##''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text])## For example if the doc file contains just SSSSSSSSssss, I get

> !# ddddSxSx
> l SSSSSSSSssss
> OJQJCJ
> &p@P !
> i4@4NormalCJOJPJQJmH <A@<Default Paragraph Font

GTimes New Roman5Symbol3Arial;Helvetica 0hKl&Kl& 0"
Oh+'0
.+,0

"Root Entry F$1TableWordDocumentSummaryInformation(DocumentSummaryInformation8

PLZ help

EDIT :
I figured out how to work with DOCX files with the python-docx library still trying to figure out doc though

Same issue as

[How to read AWS S3 stored word document (.doc and .docx) file content using AWS Lambda Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435388/how-to-read-aws-s3-stored-word-document-doc-and-docx-file-content-using-aws)

I tried the solution here with 3 votes, and using bytes io for DOC and it didn't work got bad zip file error
[Reading a docx file from s3 bucket with flask results in an AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238262/reading-a-docx-file-from-s3-bucket-with-flask-results-in-an-attributeerror)

Comment: doc format is not just ASCII symbols, it is the binary format you can not work with it like this.

Comment: Is there a way to process the binary format in django, into a string? @funnydman